# "An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA", after being told to verify I'm human twice

Tags: bug, status-norepro, captcha

Forcing a captcha challenge appending `?captcha=1` to any URL, then clicking in the box "I'm not a robot", seeing a visual challenge (this is common for me, for some reason), submit... err... why I'm seeing the captcha *again*? Try to verify again? Click the box "I'm not a robot", see the visual challenge, fill the text, ok, then hello "An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA" while the box itself is a-OK:

[image]

If I leave it for some time, the session expires and trying to validate I'm human returns "Google says: Error: Invalid reload parameters.".

Comment: No repro, but for me the captcha completes and there is no way to submit the answer.

Comment: No repro on my side either. Maybe it's your browser? @bjb568 Not moving the mouse after clicking might avoid auto-passing the captcha.

Comment: @Behaviour do you trigger the captcha? This is 100% reproducible in a brand new session.

Comment: Yes, I was asked to enter some numbers, and succeeded.